# Forward current for SMD 5630 LED?

Tags: power-supply, led, current, led-strip, led-driver

I'm trying to figure out how to choose a power supply for a 5-meter strip of SMD 5630 LEDs, and I can't wrap my head around which current values I should use.

The Samsung spec sheet for their 5630 rates their device (forward current) at 150 mA, but throughout the majority of the document, they use a forward current of 50mA.  The "50 mA" number is also referred to as "sorting current," which is a term I'm not familiar with.

So, the question: when specing a power supply for a SMD 5630, which number do I use (or perhaps better asked: under which conditions would I use one number over the other)?

[Here's the link to the spec sheet I'm referencing](https://d114hh0cykhyb0.cloudfront.net/pdfs/spmwht5225d5waq0s0.pdf).

Comment: Everything in the sheet other than that one table is done at 50mA. What current you use depends on whether or not you need to meet the specs in the datasheet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment in an answer? I'm not sure I follow what "need to meet the specs..." means in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Samsung spec sheet for their 5630 rates their device (forward current) at 150 mA, but throughout the majority of the document, they use a forward current of 50mA.

That means that you can run them continuously at 150 mA provided you don't exceed any other limits such as operating temperature. See the Forward Current Derating Curve. Note also the Relative Luminous Flux vs Temperature.

Predicting the operating temperature (of the chips) will be your problem.

> The "50 mA" number is also referred to as "sorting current," which is a term I'm not familiar with.

The LEDs are graded by colour temperature. You may have to pay extra for this if you need them with tight tolerance for a critical application.

[image]

*Figure 1. Chromaticity coordinates and diagram.*

The left graph shows the position of all the LEDs in the CIE chromaticity diagram. The right graph shows a close-up with the eight grades of "white" that are available. "Sorting" is done by machine and, according to the datasheet, is carried out at 50 mA. Depending on the colour temperature the LEDs are sorted into bins. The table above gives the X-Y coordinates of each grade.

> So, the question: when specing a power supply for a SMD 5630, which number do I use (or perhaps better asked: under which conditions would I use one number over the other)?

You can choose any value up to 150 mA provided there is adequate heat removal.

[image]

*Figure 2. A colour version of the CIE chromaticity diagram showing various white colour temperatures.*

Answer (score 0):

The 150 mA rating is in the "Absolute Maximum Rating" table.

In most semiconductor datasheets, the "Absolute Maximum Rating" table is followed by a footnote like:

"Stresses beyond those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause permanent damage to the device. These are stress ratings
only, and functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions beyond those indicated under Recommended Operating
Conditions is not implied. Exposure to absolute-maximum-rated conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability." (stolen from the TI LM311 datasheet)

It is wise to keep away from the Absolute Maximum ratings, and look elsewhere in the datasheet for typical operating conditions.